# Intersection of a Set with a twist Java

Tags: java, hashmap, runtime

So I recently got the following question in a technical interview and I thought it was pretty interesting.

Given two arrays: A = {1,2,2,4,5} and B = {1,2,6,} write code that performs the following two operations: A-B {2,4,5} and B-A {6}. Meaning, you find a common element in the other array and remove it from the original. Also if B was {1,2}, then B-A would just be {} since A contains all elements of B and B has no unique elements.

I solved this question in the following way, and I was hoping to see if anyone had any suggestions on how to possibly make it better.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
Map hashtable = new HashMap();

int a[] = {1,1,2,4,5,6,6};
int b[] = {1,2,6};

ArrayList ba = new ArrayList();
ArrayList ab = new ArrayList(); 
int[] occurances = new int[a.length];
//int occurances = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    occurances[a[i]]++;
    hashtable.put(a[i], occurances[a[i]]);

}
//System.out.println(Arrays.toString(occurances));
System.out.println(hashtable);
//find BA
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    if(hashtable.containsKey(b[i])) {
        occurances[b[i]]--;
        hashtable.put(b[i], occurances[b[i]]);
    } else ba.add(b[i]);


}
for(int i = 0; i <a.length; i++) {
    if(hashtable.containsKey(a[i]) && occurances[a[i]] != 0) {
        ab.add(a[i]);
        occurances[a[i]]--;
        hashtable.put(a[i], occurances[a[i]]);

    }

}

System.out.println("AB = " + ab);
System.out.println("BA =" + ba);

 } 
 }
```

****EDIT*****
I mistakenly called the arrays Sets when I initially posed the question. Since the arrays can have duplicate elements, they are by definition not Sets. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `Map hashtable` .... my eyes x_X

Comment: `{1,2,2,4,5}` is not a set.

Comment: A suggestion would be to implement your sets A and B with java Set. You'd have less work than implementing sets by List

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Set` which have union and intersection functions.

```
Integer a[] = {1, 2, 2, 4, 5};
Integer b[] = {1, 2, 6};

public void test() {
    // Grow the two sets from the arrays.
    Set<Integer> sa = Arrays.stream(a)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
    Set<Integer> sb = Arrays.stream(b)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
    // Make a new one so I don't damage sa or sb.
    Set<Integer> sc = new HashSet<>(sa);
    sc.removeAll(sb);
    System.out.println(sa + " - " + sb + " = " + sc);
    Set<Integer> sd = new HashSet<>(sb);
    sd.removeAll(sa);
    System.out.println(sb + " - " + sa + " = " + sd);
}
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 4, 5] - [1, 2, 6] = [4, 5]
[1, 2, 6] - [1, 2, 4, 5] = [6]
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be done just using standard [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) operations

```
Set<Integer> a; //assume initialized with {1,2,4,5}
Set<Integer> b; //assume initialized with {1,2,6}

a.removeAll(b);
System.out.println(a);
```

Should give:

```
[4, 5]
```

If instead you do:

```
b.removeAll(a);
System.out.println(b);
```

Then you'll get

```
[6]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for duplicates. If A is {1,2,2,3} a b is {2,4} A-B should be {1,2,3} with only the single 2 found in b removed. The set operations would remove all occurrences of 2 in a.

Comment: Well then A = {1,2,2,3}  by definition is NOT a set.

Comment: My mistake. I guess they're just arrays then.